# Grab redux snapshot of redux state without connecting

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a background saga that is watching the location and submits an action with the new location every time it changes and updates the location state. However, I have a component that I just want to grab the current `state.user.location` on a user interaction, but I don't want to use mapStateToProps because the component keeps re-rendering and I only want to grab the state when the user requests it and avoid constantly re-rendering.

I need the state in the background for other parts of the app.

```
reducer:
 export const updateLocation = (state, { location }) => state.merge({ location })

selector:
getLocation : state => state.user.location && state.user.location.coords || null

Component:
class SearchScreen extends PureComponent {
  render(){
    const {location} = this.props
    return(
      <Button onPress={()=>searchWithCurrentLocation(location)} />
   )}
 }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    location: UserSelectors.getLocation(state),
  }
}
```

this is my current setup, but I'd like to not pass in the location and keep re-rendering as it's not used to display the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the store accessible from anywhere like this:

file: storeProvider.js

```
var store = undefined;

export default {
    init(configureStore){
        store = configureStore();
    },
    getStore(){
        return store;
    }
};
```

file: App.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import storeProvider from './storeProvider';

const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer);
storeProvider.init(configureStore);
const store = storeProvider.getStore();

const App = () =>
    <Provider store={store} >
        <Stuff/>
    </Provider>
```

file: Component.js

```
import storeProvider from './storeProvider';

class SearchScreen extends PureComponent {
  render(){
    return(
      <Button onPress={()=> searchWithCurrentLocation(UserSelectors.getLocation(storeProvider.getStore().getState())} />
   )}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to be troubled about re-rendering if the data that has changed isn't directly affecting the components inside your render method. Let us remember that ReactDOM watches only those changed state and only update the DOM based on what's different. The render method maybe called but if nothing has really changed, **it won't affect render performance at all**.

After all that is what react is selling: reactive elements that updates changes if data changes in a smart way that it is optimized by updating only updated elements by using a virtual DOM which is ReactDOM.

Changes are first compared between the virtual DOM and the real DOM before updates are committed to the real DOM. You can read how [ReactDOM does this here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html)